# MYSQL: joining two tables and using random column from one

Tags: php, mysql

I'm rather new to mySql and I can't seem to get my head around a problem I have. What I want to do is to use a table (LessonPlans) and join it with a random image from another table (Images), but only if that image is marked with the same language as the LessonPlans. The images should continue adding only as long as there are more input from LessonPlans.

In detail:

I need to show *Name*, *Level* and *Aim* from **LessonPlans** together with a random image (*Name-img*) from **Images**, but only when both **LessonPlans** and **Images** have *Language* (for example English) in common. This should be continued as long as there are rows in **LessonPlans**, even if that means repeating **Images**.

I have tried all sorts of solutions from differnet sources, but I either get everything random, or everything repeated.

ps. I'm new to Stackoverflow so excuse me if I didn't make myself very clear

//Edit

This is the tables:

`LessonPlans
    Id
    Subject
    Language
    Level
    Aim`

`Images 
    Id 
    Name-img
    Language`

/Håkan

Comment: Kindly post schema of the tables. And a sample o/p if possible.

Comment: Ok. I gave it a try to edit the post. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @ Håkan : actually i am not clear by your question could you help me to understand?

Comment: Pawan Kumar Sharma: What I want to do is:
Run through all rows in  `LessonPlans` and for every row I want to add a random image from `Images` as long as the Language` is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -->>

```
SELECT LessonPlans.Subject , LessonPlans.Level , LessonPlans.Aim , LessonPlans.language ,
       Images.Name_img
FROM   LessonPlans INNER JOIN Images
ON  LessonPlans.language=Images.language
```

Comment: I couldn't make that work either. It just can't ask the query. I'm totally lost now...

Comment: I got the images to come out, but what happens is that it repeats each image as many times as there is a match for the Language. I only want to get as many rows as there are in LessonPlans, and a random image on each of those. In this case I have 8 LessonPlans with English, which gives me 8 of the first image in a row, followed by 8 of the 2nd etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LessonPlans.Name , LessonPlans.Level , LessonPlans.Aim , LessonPlans.language ,
       Images.img, Images.language 
FROM   LessonPlans , Images
ON  LessonPlans.commonfield=Images.commonfield
WHERE   LessonPlans.language      = 'English';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT l.Id, l.Subject, l.Language, i.`Name-img` 
        FROM LessonPlans l, Images i
        WHERE l.Language = i.Language
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) a
GROUP BY a.Subject
ORDER BY a.Id
```

You can use all fields you need. Please check this example at the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e0beb/2/0). Sometimes image names may repeat because there are few images in the sample schema.

**UPD 1:** Add specific language

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT l.Id, l.Subject, l.Language, i.`Name-img` 
        FROM LessonPlans l
        JOIN Images i
        ON l.Language = i.Language
        WHERE l.Language = 'en'
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) a
GROUP BY a.Subject
ORDER BY a.Id
```

Try this at the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e0beb/5/0)

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Is there a way to select only one language. They all line up correctly now, but if I only want English for example?

Comment: Amazing! Works perfect! You're a star @pythagor ! :)

Comment: To add the your headache. If I for some reason don't want it random anymore? Just removing ORDER BT RAND() doesn't work, and ORDER BY anything else just repeats the first image. How would I do this?